# DocumentFormat.OpenXml Modify Creator Propery of Document

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

I wish to replace Word Document Creator metadata with something else but its not persisted when calling `WordprocessingDocument.Save()`. I am utilising [DocumentFormat.OpenXML version 2.7.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/) and the following code to load and change the Creator:

```
public static SetCreator(Stream inputStream, string newCreator)
{
    //the inputStream is actually a MemoryStream
    WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(inputStream, true);
    document.PackageProperties.Creator = newCreator;
    document.Save();
    //on this point i expect the original stream to be replaced with the new one
}
```

The document is only available as stream as this thing is for a web application projects. However, when i tried to re-read the stream in debug mode, it seems the changes on the `document` instance is not persisted. Also, it does not fire any exception.

**Edit**: Further testing, using older DocumentFormat.OpenXML (version 2.0.50022. the `WordprocessingDocument` class did not have `Save()` method but instead have `Close()` method. tried to modify the code into the following and it works.. Still wondering the proper way on 2.7.2 though.

```
public static SetCreator(Stream inputStream, string newCreator)
{
    //the inputStream is actually a MemoryStream
    WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(inputStream, true);
    document.PackageProperties.Creator = newCreator;
    document.Close(); //On older version, calling this will save it into memory stream without actually closing it.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try this :

```
// Change MemoryStream by FileStream
public static SetCreator(FileStream inputStream, string newCreator)
{
    using (WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(inputStream, true))
    {
        document.PackageProperties.Creator = newCreator;
        // You shouldn't need to do document.Save()
    }
}

// Main code
path = "C:\myPath";
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    SetCreator(fs, "ME");
}
```

Comment: hi, thank you for your help. unfortunately i had no intention on using FileStream due to the fact this thing will be ran in a web application. better to lost everything rather than leaving junks in the storage.. initially i did not call the `.Save()` method, but well, despite `AutoSave` is true, it did not persist the changes.

Comment: Ok then keep the MemoryStream and try to use the "using" keyword like I did, tell me if it works ?

Comment: it seems you are misleading me regarding the `using` part. it only to wrap `disposable` items and make sure they are disposed once being used.

Comment: hi, sorry for earlier rude comment. the on i should use `using` is the `WordprocessingDocument`, not the stream. thank you.

Comment: Hi, sorry i wasn't precise also, happy that it worked.